# what is the first UML diagram to draw when creating a large scale software?

Tags: uml, software-design

Im in a confusion on the sequence of drawing UML diagrams. I cannot understand where to start drawing them. Which diagram should come first if I have the scenario with me?

Comment: See [agilemodeling.com: Requirements Envisioning: An Agile Best Practice](http://agilemodeling.com/essays/initialRequirementsModeling.htm)

Comment: Thank you I will take a look

Answer (score 3):

Start with Use Cases (and the related diagrams). Once Actors and Use Cases are identified, you can start designing a Class model. Create Collaborations realizing the Use Cases. Then inside show how the Instances of the Classes collaborate to actually realize what is needed for the Use Cases.

I recommend the ICONIX approach since that is what got me going a long time ago.

Comment: Thank you!! But I'm confused as there is only one actor. do I still need to draw the use case? I have a Business flow chart with me. and a product story board too..

Comment: Well, are you afraid of it ;-? The use cases are those basics you can discuss with business and developers (requirements alone can not really be discussed). So yes: draw the single actor and the use case(s).

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to start with Activity Diagram. I.e. make a business process analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I *always* start with a problem-domain class diagram. (Some examples of what I mean are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252780/what-is-the-common-way-to-represent-this-kind-of-diagram/34256880#34256880) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461613/game-class-diagram/29462410#29462410).) Understanding the concepts in the domain and the relationships between them is *extremely* important. If you don't understand the problem domain, everything else will be confused and brittle, including business processes, requirements, use cases, and collaborations. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663223/e-commerce-domain-model-feedback) is an example of an improper domain model, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663223/e-commerce-domain-model-feedback/26664527#26664527) are the recommended corrections.